# What's the point of using AUTO_INCREMENT and PRIMARY KEY at the same time in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key, auto-increment

In MySQL, I understand below

---

`AUTO_INCREMENT`: used to make `INT` value to increase automatically every time a user creates a row.

`PRIMARY KEY`: used to make `value` unique in that table.

---

However, I oftentimes see them used together when defining `id`.

I don't understand the point of using `AUTO_INCREMENT` with `PRIMARY KEY` since `AUTO_INCREMENT` itself would make `id` unique.

Is there any reason they are used together when creating `id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary key has three properties:

1. It is unique.
2. It is non-null.
3. There is only one per table.

Defining the key as a primary key means that it should also be used for foreign key references.

In addition, MySQL clusters the data by the primary key.  So the declaration instructs new rows to go at the "end" of the table -- meaning adjacent to the most recent inserts on the data pages.

In addition, duplicate values for the auto-incremented id could be created in various ways.  One way is that the increment counter can be reset, causing duplicates.  MySQL should be pretty thread-safe on duplicates for concurrent updates, but bugs have been reported.  As a `primary key`, no duplicates will be allowed into the table.

Comment: I still didn't get the part "Defining the key as a primary key means that it should also be used for foreign key references." is it mandatory to do so? Could you elaborate on that so that I could understand clearly, please?

Comment: @Poream3387 . . . Do you understand what a foreign key reference is?

Comment: Oh yes, I know what foreign key is. You are saying that if I were to use foreign key to reference some key, it has to be the primary key that is getting referenced right?

Comment: @Poream3387 . . . Unfortunately, it does not *have to be*.  But it is a best practice to only use primary keys for foreign key references.

Comment: Oh that's what you meant on your post! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You understand it correctly, but they are doing different things.

`PRIMARY KEY` with `AUTO_INCREMENT` means we want this column isn't duplicate on the value and it will be auto increase if we didn't set the value.

but how about we only set `AUTO_INCREMENT` it only means it will be auto increase if we didn't set the value. but didn't make sure the value is unique.

Answer (score 1):

`AUTO_INCREMENT` doesn't make the column uniqe. It only "automatically" fills a value when creating a row, if missing. But you can later update the values, or also create a row by explicitly providing the value.

`PRIMARY KEY` denies any modification sql statement that would cause 2 different entries storing equal values. So it guarantees you, that your DB is in a correct state.